# How can I search and replace in one go and for the full or selected text without visiting each search hit?

Tags: search, replace

Any advanced editor has it: `Search and Replace` to replace a chosen word with another, with search criteria "Match case" and "Match whole word only" in addition like in [notepad++](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/).

I am asking this for a selection of text and for the whole content in a file that is opened and in front, and it should be done in one go, without having to press `Enter` for each search hit.

How is that to be done in emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `M-x replace-regexp` does this. It's not bound to a key by default, so if you use it regularly you may want to do that.

You can also use `M-x query-replace-regexp`, which is bound to `C-M-%` by default. It does require you to press `enter` and then `y` for each replacement. However, if you type `!` instead of `y`, it will automatically replace all of the remaining matches in the buffer at once, so you only need to press the `!` key once.

Comment: From a beginner's view, you need to 1. press *and hold for the next three keys* `Alt`, 2. press [small letter m is enough], 3. `Shift`, 4. `5` (`Shift`+`5`= `%` of course). After the replace word, at the first search result asking you to replace, press `!` for all (as is said in the answer anyway).

Comment: `C-M-%` is a particularly convoluted keybinding, no question! It requires holding `control`, `alt`, and `shift` while pressing the `5` key. I think that's what you said, but the formatting is a bit hard to read.

Comment: Ah no, it is a bit easier, no need for pressing `Ctrl`. I need to hold `Alt` and then press `m`, still hold `Alt` and press (at first) `Shift` and then still hold `Alt` *AND* `Shift` and then press `5` (for `%` of course). That means, in the beginning, you press two keys together, in the end you press three keys together. :)))

Comment: Tyler has indicated the standard way of typing it on a US keyboard layout.  If `Alt+m` produces some kind of sticky `Ctrl` modifier for you, that's something specific to your system, and neither standard nor anything to do with Emacs (had that key sequence reached Emacs, it would normally invoke the command `back-to-indentation`, which I personally find very useful).  As such, I'm not sure that comment was as useful for beginners as you thought.

Comment: You might find it useful to investigate "sticky modifier keys" generally.  I use them, and so I get a sticky `Ctrl` by typing.... `Ctrl`.  Much simpler than typing `Alt+m` I think?!  If I want to I can type `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Shift` one at a time in order to then get `C-M-%` by typing `5`.  Or I can type them all together.  Or some individually, some together.  I can also toggle any modifier to and from a "lock" position (caps lock style) which can be super useful for repeating certain sequences in Emacs.  Sticky modifiers are great.

Comment: @phils You are right, I had not seen that `Ctrl` would then replace `Alt`+`m`. Tyler's comment makes it easier indeed.